# Xml formatting and writer settings

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I am having a below xml data created by c# code which is not in my required format. Can any one suggest how to get this done ?

C# Code for this:

```
            XmlWriterSettings xmlWriterSettings = new XmlWriterSettings();

            xmlWriterSettings.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;

            using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create("SNP.xml",xmlWriterSettings))
            {                    
                writer.WriteStartDocument();
                writer.WriteStartElement("Request","http://www.ABC.com/submit");

                foreach (DataRow row in ExcelData.Rows)
                {
                    writer.WriteStartElement(ExcelData.Rows[counter]["MyDATA"].ToString());


                    writer.WriteElementString("DATA1", ExcelData.Rows[counter]["DATA1"].ToString());
                    writer.WriteElementString("DATA2", ExcelData.Rows[counter]["DATA2"].ToString());

                    writer.WriteEndElement();
                }
                writer.WriteEndElement();
                writer.WriteEndDocument();
            }
```

Data generated by c#:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
  - <Request xmlns="http://www.timvw.be/ns">
- <MyData>
  <DATA1>91.689117127891</DATA1> 
  <DATA2>0.18242169290979</DATA2> 
  </MyData>  
  </Request>
```

however i need the xml data in below format:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" ?> 
- <Request xmlns="http://www.ABC.com/submit" xmlns:l="http://www.ABC.com/link" l:source="SRC" l:date="2014-03-05">
- <MyData l:identifier="PRAV" l:value="151.19448366182007269092408546">
  <DATA1 l:value="0.151328110447635" /> 
  <DATA2 l:value="0.6461191930062688087600920641" /> 
  <DATA3 l:value="0.144793773777417" /> 
  </MyData>
  </Request>
```

Can any one suggest what needs to be set to in c# code to get

Answer (score 1):

If you need to write the values as an XmlAttribute, try this:

```
writer.WriteStartElement("DATA1");
writer.WriteAttributeString("l:value", ExcelData.Rows[counter]["DATA1"].ToString());
writer.WriteEndElement();
```